# Is there a way to make a function check values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Its me again!

I am trying to find a value of a input and check if the value is a certain string after a button is pressed. It is confusing, but here is my code:

```js
var codeenter = document.getElementById("code")
console.log("Script")
function check() {
    var codecheck = codeenter.value;
    console.log("Started, you have clicked it.")
    if (codecheck === "109843") {
        document.getElementById("wel").innerHTML = "Hey, Sam King"
    }
}
```

```css
#title {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
}

html {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#button {
    width: 20em;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: none;
}

#name {
    text-align: center;
    object-position: center;
    margin: auto 0px;
}

#code {
    text-align: center;
}

#emsub {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: none;
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Emergency Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<body>
    <form action="./emergencysucess.html">
        <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Emergency Code">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="emsub" onclick="check">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

That all works, although I dont think the `onclick="check"` works since it doesnt even run the function because as you can see in the code it is supposed to log something but it doesnt even log that so Im a bit confused.

There is no other error messages apart from that and "emergencysucess.html" is a file.

Could you help?

Dont be confused, it does log script at the start of the .js file.

Thanks!

Comment: where are you expecting to see the logs? That code will refresh the page so client side logs will dissapear

Comment: Im expecting to see it in the console, the same place as the script log. Im kinda a newb so dont use all this cool language lol.

Comment: form onsubimit and then prevendDefualt. Button sends form - so it rerender page.

Comment: What do you mean? Post it in a answer please.

Comment: @Samyk: Well, do you *want* the form to submit to a new page?  Or do you want to stay on the current page?  Staying on the current page would allow you to see the console log statements (once you add `()` to the `check` in `onclick`), but there is no element with `id="wel"` so it's not clear what you're expecting that to do.

Comment: change the check function to be `function check(e) {` then first line inside the function add `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Yes, I have another page (Which is linked with the script) and a element with the id well. I would like it to render a new page and check this, would that be possible. Also, it isnt changing the html on the other page.

Comment: @Samyk: *"it isnt changing the html on the other page"* - Well no, it wouldn't.  Because the code is running on this page.  Consider each page as its own application.  When one unloads and another one loads, any code from that previous page is no longer running.  It sounds like you want to run some code on some other page, not on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 reasons for why this is not working:

1. In `onclick` you don't write a function, you need to call the function.
2. When you use `type="submit"` the html will try to send the form to your `action`. If you don't want that to happen, you need to `return false` from the `onclick`.

```js
var codeenter = document.getElementById("code")
console.log("Script")

function check() {
  var codecheck = codeenter.value;
  console.log("Started, you have clicked it.")
  if (codecheck === "109843") {
    document.getElementById("wel").innerHTML = "Hey, Sam King"
  }
}
```

```css
#title {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#button {
  width: 20em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: none;
}

#name {
  text-align: center;
  object-position: center;
  margin: auto 0px;
}

#code {
  text-align: center;
}

#emsub {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<form action="./emergencysucess.html">
  <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Emergency Code">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="emsub" onclick="check(); return false">Login</button>
</form>
<div id="wel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default action of the submit button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```js
var codeenter = document.getElementById("code")
console.log("Script")
function check(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    var codecheck = codeenter.value;
    console.log("Started, you have clicked it.")
    if (codecheck === "109843") {
        document.getElementById("wel").innerHTML = "Hey, Sam King"
    }
}
```

```css
#title {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
}

html {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#button {
    width: 20em;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: none;
}

#name {
    text-align: center;
    object-position: center;
    margin: auto 0px;
}

#code {
    text-align: center;
}

#emsub {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: none;
    width: 10em;
    height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Emergency Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<body>
    <form action="./emergencysucess.html">
        <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Emergency Code">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="emsub" onclick="check(event)">Login</button>
    </form>
    <p id="wel" />
</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```